# how to display image in datebase with a tile

Tags: php, upload

i am trying to make a page for me to upload files to with a tile i cant get it to show up on the website

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

    $title = $_POST["title"];

 #file name with a random number so that similar dont get replaced
 $pname = rand(1000,10000)."-".$_FILES["file"]["name"];

#temporary file name to store file
$tname = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

 #upload directory path
$uploads_dir = 'images';
#TO move the uploaded file to specific location
move_uploaded_file($tname, $uploads_dir.'/'.$pname);

#sql query to insert into database
$sql = "INSERT into fileup(title,image) VALUES('$title','$pname')";

if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){

echo "File Sucessfully uploaded";
}
else{
    echo "Error";
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here I save the path of the image into the DB.Then retrieve the image source vai DB.

> for photo uploading .

```
$folder ="../uploads/";
$destFile = $folder . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
$sourdeFile = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];


if(move_uploaded_file($sourdeFile,$destFile)){
    echo "File has been uploaded";
    $photo = basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
}else{
    echo $_FILES['photo']['error'];
    $photo = "images/default.png";
}
$sql= "INSERT INTO car(photo) VALUES('$photo') ";
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
   echo
    "
    <script>
    alert ('Your Image successfully upladed');
    window.location='newindex.php';
    </script>
    ";

}else{

    echo "Error:".mysqli_error($con);
}
```

> To view uploaded images

```
  $sql=" SELECT *  FROM car";
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);


   <img src="Your default path name/<?=$row["photo"];?>" class="img-thumbnail" style="max-width:400px;max-height:350px;"/>
```

In here photo will be uploaded into a folder named uploads. At the begoining of the upload name of the image will be save in to DB  table . Then to view uploaded images `img src` will use the default path name with photo name at the DB. hope you can grab something from this. Also please note that this is only a example. When using `SQL` please use parameterized query to avoid `SQL injections`. Thanks